Körner-Contardi reaction: Lost to history?
When we talk about synthesizing aryl halides, the more famous reaction is Friedel-Crafts halogenation which is still used commercially to produce chlorobenzene. If we consider synthesis through diazonium salt (which is already versatile), the more famous is Sandmeyer reaction which involves cuprous salt and corresponding halogen acid. Another variation of the reaction is the Gattermann reaction (not to be confused with the formylation reaction) which uses copper metal and corresponding halogen acid. I learned one more variation of the reaction which is Körner-Contardi reaction which uses cupric salt + corresponding halogen acid. The only information I found is here. I couldn't find any more details of the reaction nor the publication leading to believe the reaction is lost in the past.
Can anyone provide some information/context on this reaction? Is it lost because the other three reactions were more prevalent?

E. Noelting, "The Nitro Derivatives of Benzine and Toluene", Color Trade Journal, Vol. 3, No. 1, Jul.-Dec. 1918, pp. 120-122 appears to describe this work? I can see that Körner and Contardi had three publications in vol. 23 (1914) of Atti della Accademia nazionale dei Lincei which are likely closely related, the one starting at p. 464 being the middle one. Some volumes of this journal have been digitized and are available online, but volume 23 doesn't seem to be among them.

Three papers probably not related. I was able to track down copies of the other two 1914 publications: A. Contardi, G. Körner, "Benzine nitrosostituite, ottenute dai corrispondenti aminoderivati", Rend. Mat. Acc. Lincei, s. 5, v. 23 (1914) 1, pp. 281 - 286 :: A. Contardi, G. Koerner, "La trinitrobenzina asimmetrica 1. 2. 4." Rend. Mat. Acc. Lincei, s. 5, v. 23 (1914) 1, pp. 633 - 635. Still looking for the paper on p. 464ff.

Publication from the question: G. Koerner, A. Contardi, "La trinitrobenzina vicinale 1. 2. 3 ; un nuovo trinitrotoluene e prodotti dinitroalogeno-sostituiti corrispondenti"
Rend. Mat. Acc. Lincei, s. 5, v. 23 (1914) 2, pp. 464 - 471 :: Follow-up work: G. Körner, A. Contardi, ""Il quinto trinitrotoluene, (ε), e prodotti dinitro-alogeno-sostituiti corrispondenti", Rend. Mat. Acc. Lincei, s. 5, v. 24 (1915) 1, pp. 888 - 896

Wikipedia has a brief article on G. Körner, originally Wilhelm Körner from Germany. I have not been able to find much about Angelo Contardi (1877–1951) yet.

@njuffa The article in the Treccani Encyclopedia seems quite comprehensive to me.

@M. Lonardi Thanks for the pointer, which hopefully will help the asker. Looks comprehensive. I am not going to attempt to write an answer, as the question focuses on chemistry, and I have no expertise in that. Plus my knowledge of Italian is minimal. For the biography of Contardi, I found these references: A. Ercoli, "Angelo Contardi 26-VII-1877 -- 23-III-1951." Il Farmaco, Scienza e Technica, Vol. 6, No. 3, May - Jun. 1951, pp. 408-16. :: G. Lantini, "Angelo Contardi 1877-1951." Bollettino dell'Istituto Sieroterapico Milanese, Vol. 30, No. 7-8, Jul. - Aug. 1952, pp. 430-432.
